# RrequireJS optimizer and loading dynamic paths after optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization, gruntjs, requirejs

I have a grunt task with requirejs and am running the optimizer.

I load a lot of external files which are not always needed at run time, usually I only need a handful of core files. Then based on user decisions I load certain files during run time.

Ex:

```
define(["backbone",     'text!data/filePaths.json'],
    function(Backbone,   filePaths) {
        'use strict';

        return Backbone.Model.extend({

            initialize: function(){
                // parse the file paths, there could be a hundred here
                this.filePaths = JSON.parse(filePaths);
            },

            // dynamically add a file via this function call
            addFile: function(id){
                var self = this;

                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){     

                    // load files dynamically based on the id passed in
                    require([self.filePaths[id].path], function(View){
                        resolve(new View());
                    });


                });
            }

        });

    }

);
```

the file paths json might look like this:

```
"ONE": {
    "name": "BlueBox",
    "path": "views/box/Blue"
},
"TWO": {
    "name": "RedBox",
    "path": "views/box/Red"
},
etc...
```

The issue is that this does not work with the optimizer for me.

When I run my app with the optimized file I get:

```
Uncaught Error: undefined missing views/box/Red
```

**Update:**

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    requirejs: {
        desktopJS: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: "public/js/app",
                wrap: true,
                // Cannot use almond since it does not currently appear to support requireJS's config-map
                name: "../libs/almond",
                preserveLicenseComments: false,
                optimize: "uglify2",
                uglify2: {
                    // mangle: false,
                    // no_mangle: true,
                    // stats: true,
                    // "mangle-props": false,
                    "max-line-len": 1000,
                    max_line_length: 1000
                },
                uglify: {
                    mangle: false,
                    no_mangle: true,
                    stats: true,
                    "mangle-props": false,
                    max_line_length: 1000,
                    beautify: true
                },
                mainConfigFile: "public/js/app/config/config.js",
                include: ["init/DesktopInit"],
                out: "public/js/app/init/DesktopInit.min.js"
            }
        },
        desktopCSS: {
            options: {
                optimizeCss: "standard",
                cssIn: "./public/css/desktop.css",
                out: "./public/css/desktop.min.css"
            }
        }
    },
```

Note: if I use the unoptimized version, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer is unable to trace dependencies for `require` calls that do not have dependencies as an array of string literals. Your call is an example of a `require` call that the optimizer cannot process because the list of dependencies is computed at run-time:

```
require([self.filePaths[id].path], function(View){
```

The reason for this is simple: the optimizer does not evaluate your modules as it optimizes them. Anyway, the number of possible values for `self.filePaths[id].path` is potentially infinite so there's no way the optimizer could handle all cases.  So when the optimizer optimizes your code, the modules that should be loaded by this `require` call are not included in the bundle. One solution, which you've touched upon in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32874184/1906307) is to use `include` to **include all possible modules that could be loaded by that `require` call.**

As you point out, if you can have hundred of modules, this means including them all in the bundle produced by the optimizer. Is there an alternative? Yes, there is.

You can produce a bundle that includes only the other modules of your application and **leave the modules that are to be loaded by the `require` call above to be loaded individually rather than as part of the bundle.** Ah, but there's a problem with the specific configuration you show in the question. You have a comment that says you cannot use Almond. Yet, in fact you do use it, right there on the next line. (And you also have it in your answer.) The problem is that one of Almond's restrictions is that it does not do dynamic loading. That's the very first restriction in the [list of restrictions](https://github.com/jrburke/almond#restrictions). **You'd have to use a full-featured AMD loader for this, like RequireJS itself.**

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I didn't actually read up on Almond, but once I switched to require my problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the answer, just a way "around" my application not working.

I believe the only way I can circumvent this is with the **include** configuration

Ex:

```
requirejs: {
    desktopJS: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: "public/js/app",
            wrap: true,
            name: "../libs/almond",
            optimize: "uglify2",
            uglify2: {
                "max-line-len": 1000,
                max_line_length: 1000
            },
            mainConfigFile: "public/js/app/config/config.js",
            include: ["init/DesktopInit", "views/box/Blue"], // include the file here, all of a sudden the error goes away for that file.
```

Though this becomes cumbersome for when I have a hundred files. I don't want to build the whole thing with all my files included, I would like a set of optimized files, and a bunch of other ones which can be required dynamically.